# A Maze of Sorts

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, acrostic

With my [last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70492/enter-the-vermillion) seeming to be a rather difficult one to solve, I figured I would write a new one. I was inspired by [another riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/riddled-and-dismembered) here on Puzzling by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers). Though this one is not as good as his, I hope you all enjoy it.

> In stifling successions, columns all directions;
>
> Together in erected, obvious green collections.
>
> Erratic labyrinths, exotic by nature;
>
> Nodeless, keyless, devious behavior.

**What Am I?**

**How do I relate to the title?**

Comment: I like your riddles, but they are sometimes hard

Comment: Also, labyrinths can also be the inner part of your ear, so could it possibly be the ear canal, even thoguh applying the other lines would make one weird, icky ear canal?

Comment: @Duck I'm glad you enjoy my riddles! I can't make them all easy though! The easier ones don't usually last very long which doesn't give newcomers a chance to solve; and who knows, they may be the next El-Guest as we've seen his reputation explode since he arrived. When do we get the next Duck riddle?

Comment: I am thinking of making homophone riddle 2

Comment: There, I have made it

Comment: It is not yet correctly answered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> **Corn**

This is hinted by

> Taking the first letters of some columns. e.g. The second word of each line gives us **SILK**. Doing so for the third and fourth give **SEED** and **COB**. They are all words related to corn.

Line 1

> Corn is usually planted in large fields in rows/columns.

Line 2

> When corn is fully grown, you will see many green, erect stalks.

Line 3

> Because corn is grown close to each other, the fields end up being quite dense, so it is easy to get lost in them as you would a labyrinth. Corn has also been historically exotic. It wasn't until we bred it over generations for it to become a common source of food.

Line 4

> This might reference the data structure that is nodeless (not a tree) and keyless (not an array). One would be the stack. The devious behavior might be the action of popping items off the stack, and popping is what we do to corn to make popcorn.

How it relates to the title

> Corn is also known as **maize**, which is a homophone for **maze**, so it's a "maze" in that sense.

Comment: (rot13)pbea znmrf ner nyfb n guvat (gvgyr pyhr)

Comment: Your answer is correct; I would like to point out that there was a fourth word hidden in the acrostic (in a rather unusual way); rot13(Vagreabqr jnf uvqqra va gur svefg jbeq bs rnpu cnffntr). This is actually the reason behind the wording; though your analogy for that line is exactly what I had in mind!

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess

> Transistors on a chip

Line 1

> Drawn as a circuit diagram, the circuit between drain and source in a mosfet transistor looks kind of like a column. Chips usually contain dense forests of transistors.

Line 2

> Transistors are combined to make higher level components. For example, transistors can be used to make logic gates, which in turn can be used together to make other higher level components, such as an Arithmetic Logic Unit. Maybe the green refers to how some chips are colored green?

Line 3

> Millions of transistors etched on a chip can look like a labyrinth.

Line 4

> Nodeless and keyless because looking at an individual transistor is not very useful. Although transistors have useful properties, an individual transistor only contributes to the function of the higher level component is a part of. Electrons/Electricity can be described as devious.

The title:

> electrons traveling through paths in a maze of transistors.

Comment: This was a very good guess! +1 From me. Not the answer though.