# A Colorful Riley

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

Another simple Riley for the community while I continue to put my next story riddle together. This one will hopefully take a little longer to solve. Good luck to you all!

> Pry for the prefix, all you need is my eye; or was it yours? Just get rid of the why.
>
> Into the infix, stare for a while; it’ll slip past you, while it sits back and smiles.
>
> Now for the suffix, in my music its blaring; I think it’s time for another red herring.
>
> Keen on music? This band knows the way; with Floyd you’re not wrong, quite an album to play.

In all fairness to the community this one isn’t so simple, but I can guarantee you’re overthinking it. The answers are contained in the riddle, as with most of my puzzles. You just have to figure out where.

Comment: oh wow, reading the first line, knowing the answer..... how could I not see that

Comment: The whole line is a red herring to hide it :)

Comment: This is really good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## New Answer:

Could you be

> **PRISM**?

`Pry for the prefix, all you need is my eye; or was it yours? I don’t know why.`

> **PRI**. "Pry" for the prefix.

`Into the infix, stare for a while; it’ll slip past you, while it sits back and smiles.`

> <s>**IS**. There is an album called [**Prism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(Katy_Perry_album)) by Katy Perry, with a song called [**I**nternational **S**mile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxi691KeT94).
>  **I**. You stare with your **eyes**. The actions "sl**i**p, s**i**ts, sm**i**les" all contain **i**.</s> 
>  **S**. You can **s**tare at it. The actions "**s**lip, **s**its, **s**miles" all begin with **s**. Also, "slip past you" $\to$ "slip past u" $\to$ "slip pa**st u**" which are letters of the alphabet in their order starting from **s**.

`Now for the suffix, in my music its blaring; I think it’s time for another red herring.`

> **M** for **m**usic? This is the only part I cannot explain, but music is definitely related to the answer.

`Keen on music? This band knows the way; with Floyd you’re not wrong, quite an album to play.`

> There is an album by [**Pink Floyd**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_Floyd), also called [**Prism**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&client=safari&rls=en&q=pink+floyd+prism&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLSz9U3MCwvs6zIU-LRT9c3rCxMTi7JKanSEs9OttLPLS3OTNZPLCrJLC6xSsxJKs0tfsQYxC3w8sc9YSnPSWtOXmN05sKlUkiDi801rySzpFJIjotPCskqDQYpHi4kPg8AkGE8DIoAAAA&npsic=-1766&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRnZrnq8jdAhUYAogKHbZJDBYQ-BYIYw&tbs=kac:1,kac_so:0).

$$$$
**Title:**

> [image: COLOURFUL] 
>  
>  That is **colourful**!

Also,

> The acrostics spell **PINK** as it refers to **Pink Floyd**.

---

## Original Answer:

Could you be

> **EVIL**?

`Pry for the prefix, all you need is my eye; or was it yours? I don’t know why.`

> **E**. There is something known as the [**e**vil **e**ye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_eye) which would be all you n**ee**d, as this answer is very much related. It is said that people with "looks that can kill" have an evil eye, and you might not know why.

`Into the infix, stare for a while; it’ll slip past you, while it sits back and smiles.`

> **V**. It comes after **U** (you) and looks like it is smiling (if I add eyes, it looks like it is smiling: $\stackrel{\bullet\bullet}{\rm V}$) Another word for a "slip" could be en**v**elope, and staring relates to eyes $\to$ evil eyes.

`Now for the suffix, in my music its blaring; I think it’s time for a red herring.`

> **IL**. In music, there are **pieces**. In the OP's "pieces" (riddles), there is one main thing that is red: the [**Vermillion**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70492/enter-the-vermillion/70759). The part that is blaring in the word (that occurs the most) is "**il**" (Verm**illi**on). Also, **villains** can be pretty evil sometimes, and that word contains "**il**".

`Keen on music? This band knows the way; with Floyd you’re not wrong, quite an album to play.`

> This refers to [**Pink Floyd**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_Floyd) who sang a song called [**Money**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0kcet4aPpQ), which is commonly referred to as "the root of all **evil**". In fact, that is one of the actual lyrics to the song (namely, *"Money, so they say, is the root of all evil today."*)!

$$$$

**Title:**

> I cannot really explain the title, but the name **Lucifer** is hidden in it (*A* ***C***${}$o${}$***l***${}$*o*${}$***rfu***${}$*l R*${}$***i***${}$*l*${}$***e***${}$*y* $\to$ **Clrfuie** $\to$ **luCifer**).

Also,

> The acrostics spell **PINK** as it refers to **Pink Floyd** and the "colour of evil". I mean, guess who's the bad guy in the following picture. 
>  
>  [image: PICTURE] 
>  
>  Clearly, it is the guy with the red (**pink**ish) lightsaber.

Comment: Way over the top but quite enjoyable. Not the answer though; the band is correct and they can help you :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ Over the top for one of *your* riddles? I find that hard to believe! Hahah, I am glad I got the last part correct. I'll see if I can keep digging (and get on with the "Son at War" hint) :P

Comment: The pieces are literally in the riddle. Examine each line carefully.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Wait... I think I'm onto something... this looks promising... I am going to edit my answer and write a second one :P

Comment: Waiting for the answer! :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ edited! Let's hope, fingers crossed...

Comment: @user477343, i think rot13(Qnex Fvqr bs gur Zbba, bar bs gur orfg nyohzf bs nyy gvzr, nyfb unf n cevfz ba vg)

Comment: @SteveV Yeah, it has some kinda triangle. Or do you mean a song called that? :P

Comment: The infix is wrong but everything else was right. :) I’ll accept as answer, but hopefully you can find the infix! Think similar to the suffix.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Okay, okay. Think! **Edit:** I have edited the infix part :P

Comment: Still wrong lol the other one :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ alright, if I haven't got it, I think I know what letter to include :) **Edit:** YES! WOOO!

Answer (score 1):

#### Partial Answer

> The first letter of each line spells "PINK"

Comment: The infix could be rot13(V) and the Floyd part goes with the word. :)

Comment: Not quite @QuantumTwinkie but it will help you find the word.

Answer (score 1):

Sure its wrong, but is it

> Golden Earring?

Pry for the prefix, all you need is my eye; or was it yours? I don’t know why.

> Golden as in Goldeneye

Into the infix, stare for a while; it’ll slip past you, while it sits back and smiles.

> i only see "near", which I suppose may slip past you and become far

Now for the suffix, in my music its blaring; I think it’s time for a red herring.

> blARING and heRRING

Keen on music? This band knows the way; with Floyd you’re not wrong, quite an album to play.

> they know the way, they use Radar (Love).  Not sure on the Floyd part.  Perhaps that and Pink are the red-dish herring

I think you need to look up the word "simple" :)

Comment: Way off, but I like the answer. Also, simple is a subjective word right? Lol Oh wait, nope, just used to mislead an audience. Lol